# Table vertical line

Tags: tables, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Too long vertical lines in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42156/too-long-vertical-lines-in-table)

In the following table, the first vertical line is higher than
the second. How do I correct this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}% 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % 
        \def\inputGnumericTable{}                                 %%
    \usepackage{ucs}                                              %%
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                                  %%
    \usepackage{color}                                            %%
    \usepackage{array}                                            %%
    \usepackage{longtable}                                        %%
    \usepackage{calc}                                             %%
    \usepackage{multirow}                                         %%
    \usepackage{hhline}                                           %%
    \usepackage{ifthen}                                           %%

\begin{document} % no fim.

\begin{table}[h]\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1,5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1,5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1,5cm}} \\
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

There is a spurious newline before the start of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}% 
\usepackage{array}                                            %%
\begin{document} % no fim.
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}} \\
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This reproduces the error. The following doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}% 
\usepackage{array}                                            %%
\begin{document} % no fim.
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}} 
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note the lack of `\\` on line 4. (scroll right to see it.)