# longtable: extra table structure after last entry

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, longtable

My long table extends one more column after the last row and is not smooth. What am I missing?

```
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
\caption{sample table with extra lines} \\
\hline
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{symbol} \\ \hline
100505607 & LOC100505607\\ \hline
100506282 & unknown \\ \hline
100506342 & unknown \\ \hline
\label{tab:exclusivelyByAbid}
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\label` needs to be inside the `\caption` argument (or in a later table cell), but not, as in the posted code, in a cell on its own on the last row, otherwise `longtable` will generate a spurious last row to hold the write node.